# How to change task's priority?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

How to change task's priority in Windows Server 2003 Scheduled task?

I see it's possible in Windows Server 2008 and R2. I'm wondering if it's possible in Server 2003 too?
In 2008 it's possible through a XML walk-around, which is not possible in 2003. I'm wonndering if there's another way? using API or something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to edit the priority is to select the task, export it to XML, open up the xml in Notepad, set the priority and import it back in.